# Problem with nginx configuration on a docker

Tags: docker, nginx, server, devops

I put up a web application on 4 containers: database, backend frontend and nginx. I disabled the host ngnix because it was blocking the one in the container, the frontend in the application displays correctly, but when I try to send a login query in the console I get this error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.2:8000/login' from origin
> 'http://server_public_address_without_ports' has been blocked by
> CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the
> resource is in more-private address space `local`.

The backend is fired this way

```
exec gunicorn chemical_project.wsgi:application -b 127.0.0.2:8000
```

The nginx docker confguration looks as follows:

```
upstream backend { server backend:8000; }

server {
    listen 80;

    location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
            #proxy_pass: http://127.0.0.2:8000
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    }

    location /static/rest_framework/ {
            root /static/;
    }

    location / {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://public_host_adress';
            root /var/www/frontend;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
```

}

Frontend is build like this:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]
```

and the main docker-compose file look like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db
#    networks:
#      - djangonetwork
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: *****
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ********
      POSTGRES_DATABASE: *****
      POSTGRES_ROOT_PASSWORD: ********
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - ":5432:5432"
    expose:
      - 5432
  backend:
    volumes:
      - static:/static
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: ./backend
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    expose:
      - 8000

  frontend:
    build:
      context: frontend
    volumes:
      - frontend:/app/build
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/static
      - frontend:/var/www/frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    expose:
      - 80
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend

volumes:
  static:
  frontend:
```

I probably don't understand something or have misconfigured it, however, I am not familiar with containers. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `CORS` issue, not a `nginx` issue.

If your frontend is hosted on `http://server_public_address_without_ports`, make sure you are calling `http://server_public_address_without_ports/api/login` to access your backend.

> Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.2:8000/login' from origin 'http://server_public_address_without_ports' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space local.

This error happened because you are calling the backend API directly through `127.0.0.2:8000`, which is differ from the url of your frontend hosted.

So, in your frontend, replace all the local backend API endpoint `http://127.0.0.1:8000` with env vars, and substitute with the proper API endpoint with public IP `http://public_ip/api` when compiling production build. You can control this using `.env` etc.

Comment: I followed your advice, however, now I get a different message when trying to request 
        
POST http://server_public_address_without_ports/login 405 (Not Allowed)